# Checking if an EasyMock mock is on replay mode/state

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

Is it possible to determine if an EasyMock mock is on replay mode?

Something like:

```
if (EasyMock.isReplayed(mock))
  // do something
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to check the `state` of a mock you need to **unProxy** your mock and check the state set for that mock, and one state is the `ReplayState`. As EasyMock works with Java Proxies, this is quite easy:

```
EasyMock.replay(mock); // setting replay state to a mock object

// stripping proxy and getting the invocation handler
InvocationHandler invocationHandler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(mock); 


// for easyMock, invocation handler holds the state of the mock 
ObjectMethodsFilter objectMethodsFilter = (ObjectMethodsFilter) invocationHandler; 

// not the not so elegant part:
// this: objectMethodsFilter.getDelegate().getControl().getState() 
// retrieves  the state instance that can be checked if it is an 
// instance of ReplayState.class
boolean inReplayState = objectMethodsFilter.getDelegate()
    .getControl().getState() instanceof ReplayState;
```

And thats it! This will print `true` because was already set to `Replay`

Maybe for version 3.1 you could use:

```
ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(mock).getState() instanceof ReplayState
```

[`ClassExtensionHelper.getControl()` javadoc](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/internal/ClassExtensionHelper.html#getControl%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: What I really want to determine is if the `replay(mock)` method was called at all.

Comment: ohhh I got it... let me correct the answer ;) I used it some time ago!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Wow, that seems really complicated.  Is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: I haven't tested it quite yet.  I wanted to make sure there wasn't a way in the existing API.

Comment: And if you take a look into EasyMock class code you will find it as a private method: 
    private static MocksControl getControl(Object mock) {
        ObjectMethodsFilter handler = (ObjectMethodsFilter) Proxy
                .getInvocationHandler(mock);
        return handler.getDelegate().getControl();
    }
that is more or less this: `objectMethodsFilter.getDelegate().getControl()`